# Vue.js: two-way data binding using object with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm having problems binding input data to object properties. I'm iterating through an object to generate input fields from its attributes, but the data binding won't work using v-model. Here's my code (the console log remains empty):

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for='value, key in fields'>
    {{ key }}: <input v-model='value'>
</div>
<button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>

<script>

new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    fields: {
        id: 123,
        name: 'abc'
    }
},
methods: {
    add: function(){
          console.log('id: ' + this.fields.id)
          console.log('name: ' + this.fields.name)
    }
}
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to use `fields[key]` with v-model as `value` will not work there, it is an local variable of `v-for`.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for='(value, key) in fields'>
    {{ key }}: <input v-model="fields[key]">
  </div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

See working demo [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ywdoqo5q/).

Comment: Good grief this is subtle, but a very clear and concise explanation!  Vue's documentation should have this in the Caveats section (this detail was surprisingly difficult to find through google and SO).